# Is this the right way to detect a "Partition is full" exception in cosmos db? (403.1014)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

To catch a "partition is full" exception, I'm filtering for HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) and checking the **x-ms-substatus** response header for "1014".  Is this correct and reliable?  I can't find any documentation confirming this is correct.  It works NOW, seemingly, but I don't want to rely on undocumented effects.

My exception filter: `catch (DocumentClientException e) when (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden && e.ResponseHeaders["x-ms-substatus"] == "1014")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation as of now to handle this as it's part of programming. What you already have in place should be good. However you could make use of the existing [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentclientexception?view=azure-dotnet) in order to make it generic